# Get individual elements matching multiple selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I am selecting as follows:

```
$('li', "#container").draggable({
    /* blah */
});
```

How do I get the individual class attributes for those elements selected so that I can something along the lines of

```
$('li', "#container").draggable({
    /* blah */
}).attr("name", "insert name of individual img");
```

The markup is as follows:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="blah">
        <img src="" class="update" name="I Want This" width="40" height="40" />
    </li>
    <li class="blah">
        <img src="" class="update" name="I Want this too" width="40" height="40" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to use each() for this:

```
$("li", "#container").draggable({
  // ...
}).each(function() {
  $(this).attr("name", $(this).find("img").attr("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [jQuery.each()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each#objectcallback) method to iterate over the collection of jQuery Objects

```
$('li',"#container").draggable({
    /* blah */
}).each(function() {
    $(this).attr("name", "insert name of individual img");
});
```

Comment: Thank you once again for your help!